# doing a merge/mesh on two or more topojson features

Tags: geospatial, topojson

I have a few sets of map data (sometimes many depending on the situation). For this example, each topojson feature object has an ID. I would like to be able to take a few features and create new ones where they overlap with an ID of the sum of the overlapping features.

For example, if I have 3 features (from 3 separate topojson files) and there are overlapping features with IDs `3, 4, 2` I would like to create a new feature where they overlap with an ID of `9`. Any ideas on how to do this? Is this something that can be done directly with topojson?

Comment: [This question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/71327/how-to-merge-topojson-features) should help.

Comment: Thanks @LarsKotthoff, I think what I'm struggling with is that the objects don't exist in one object. They are separate features from separate `d3.json` calls. Any quick ideas on how to work around with that?

Comment: I would merge everything into one on the backend, probably by merging the data before giving it to TopoJSON.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I was afraid so. I have to figure out a solution where backend merging isn't required. Thanks for your help!

Comment: The TopoJSON format isn't particularly amenable to merging I'm afraid.